# php method unexpected t_string

Tags: php, arrays, methods, syntax-error

I am working on a php method that giving me a syntax error on the third line of the method body. Commenting out the line does not do anything for me. Only by commenting out the entire method, does it actually go away. Am I missing something here?

```
public function get(Array $array) {
    if(array_key_exists('data', $array)) {
        if($array['data'] == '*') {
            $fieldString = '*';
        } else { 
            $fieldString = '';
            for($x=0; $x < count($array['data']); $x++) {
                if($x == count($array['data']) - 1 ) {
                    $fieldString .= $array['data'][$x].' ';
                } else {
                    $fieldString .= $array['data'][$x].', ';
                }
            }
        }
        if(array_key_exists('table', $array)) {
            $table = $array['table'];
        }
        if(array_key_exists('conditions', $array)) {
            $condition = $array['conditions'];
            $filter = '';
            foreach($condition['cond'] as $cond) {
                if(array_key_exists('type', $cond)) { 
                    $filter .= $cond['type'].' ';
                }
                if(array_key_exists('field', $cond)) {
                    $filter .= $cond['field']. ' = '; 
                }
                if(array_key_exists('value', $cond)) {
                    $filter .= $cond['value'];
                }
            }
        }

        $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT ".$fieldString." FROM ".$table. " ".$filter);
        $response = $result->fetch_assoc();
        if(!empty($response)) {
            return $response;
        } else {
            echo 'response array from get model is empty';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<h3>array data not set for _get() in model </h3>';
    }    
}
```

Comment: What line gives the error?

Comment: Can it be that you're missing a `}` ?

Comment: Just remove the word public ;)

Comment: I copied your method into a class definition and got no error. There must be something different between what you posted and your real code.

Comment: Try posting the rest of your code.  I just copied your method and it parses just fine.

Comment: You probably have a missing quote somewhere before this function. Any decent IDE with syntax highlighting should make it obvious where the error is.

Comment: if($array['data'] == '*') { this is my line that it actually points to, but commenting it out doesnt change anything. This is after I went through change the structure of the method body and that line completely. error remained the entire time

Comment: You should print out the $array to see if its what you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

Is the method contained within the class. Sometimes I accidentally put a class function at the end of the class file but outside the ending }. If it is not a class method, remove 'public'.

Comment: I get a `parse error` when I try to define this method outside a class, not `unexpected T_STRING`.

Comment: Good catch. I saw (T_PUBLIC) and made the connection.

Comment: I put this method inside a class Model { function get(){ ... } }. I did check to make sure that class braces closed around it and all other code in this class is commented out to eliminate other factors

Answer (score 0):

Change  $mysqli->query() to $this->mysqli->query()

I am presuming you created a class method mysqli but you are calling it without '$this'.
If mysqli is the php function, it should be mysqli_query($this->token, "query")

Although, you should be getting ' Undefined variable' with this. In any event $mysqli is undefined in this method.